# Get Not Matching Records Sql Server Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

One is Demand table and another table is VarientCountry i want only thoes varient from demand table which has no country mapping in varientcountry table

Demand Table

```
Id Varient Country
1     v1       India
2     v2       NULL
3     v3       Nepal
4     v4       Japan
```

VarientCountry Table

```
Id Varient Country
1    v1       India
2    v1       Uk
3    v2       China
4    v1       Indonisia
5    v3       Nepal
6    v4       Egland
7    v4       Null
```

I want Excepted Result like as

```
Id Varient Country
1     v1       UK
3     v2       China
6     v4       England
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `except` one.

You have to select the record from `demand` table `except` record from `varientCountry` table.  This is the right one.

```
   select varient, Country
    from demand
    except
    select varient, country
    from varientCountry;
```

You will get the below output

```
Id Varient Country
1     v2       Null
2     v4       Japan
```

Comment: If you run this query you will get below varient Country
v2 NULL
v4 Japan

Answer (score 2):

You can use `except` if you can live without the ids:

```
select Varient, Country
from VarientCountry
except
select varient, country
from demand;
```

If you need the ids, I'd go for `not exists`:

```
select vc.*
from varientcountry vc
where not exists (select 1
                  from demand d
                  where d.varient = vc.varient and
                        (d.country = vc.country or d.country is null and vc.country is null)
                 );
```